# How to trim flv file without FFMPEG

Tags: php, video, video-streaming, video-capture, video-processing

Hi All.

We want to trim uploaded videos in certain time limit. like we want to trim our video to first 30 seconds on run time. we dont want to use FFMPEG for this purpose as it need to do certain configuration and we are not on live server.

so please refer some classes or codes that cam fulfill our such requirements.

we do not have any big libraries and codes that best fits here and complete our all requirements. we are not interested in FFMPEG nor we will use it. so please refer things other than that.

we have used:

```
trimMp3->cut_mp3('oldfile', 'newfile');
```

For this purpose as well but no good lucks as it is only used for mp3 triming. Can anyone please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think, that you really understand what are you asking for. To do that, you'll need a huge library of video and audio encoders/decoders written on PHP.
Which video/audio format do you use?

Comment: basically we want to upload a video and split it into 2 videos. one with 30 sec preview and other is full video.

Comment: currently we are not using anyone as we are unable to find the one who best fits here.

Comment: can you please help us getting one?

Comment: Yes, but which codecs your videos use? h264, vc-1, ac3, mp3, ...? There is no "magical" solution.

Comment: sir we are uploading a simple flv file for this purpose without hazing of any codecs

Comment: There is no such thing as "any codecs". Flv is just a container.

Comment: Read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_container_format, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_file_format, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats.

Comment: bhai please listen. is it possible or not?

Comment: There is no answer to your question, because the question itself lacks information. You need to restate it and probably do some research.

Comment: If assume, that you are using h264+mp3, than you can write some kind of wrapper class on PHP for x264 (http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html) using exec() function and mp3 class you mentioned.

Comment: basically we have mentioned it for a example that we have used this etc process and create a short version of mp3 file but now we want to create the same for flv file.

Comment: thanks for the help. so what we expects from you is to give us some php class or code that can help us here.

Answer (score 0):

FLV is an extremely simple file format. Writing the code to do this yourself in PHP should be pretty easy.

Se Annex E in this document
http://download.macromedia.com/f4v/video_file_format_spec_v10_1.pdf

Simple read in each FLV tag, if the timestamp is less than 30000 write it to a new file. if it is greater, throw it away.